# Excel formulas - how to make a cell blank down the page

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am having trouble figuring out the formula for my budget.

Cells look like this

```
 A           B         C        D
DATE        WEEKLY     BILLS   TOTAL
2015         $50                $1,956.73
Jan 16       $50        $70     $1,936.73
```

I want to formula cell D so that when I insert data every week into cells B & C it will add my Total in D carrying the balance from the previous balance in D.  As this is a yearly budget I am finding that every formula I use, carry's the total in D all the way down the page.  I want cell D to be blank down the page, until which time I enter data in B & C.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an IF and an OR to make sure either WEEKLY or BILLS are populated:

```
=(IF(OR(B3>0,C3>0),D2+B3-C3,""))
```

[image]

This checked if B3 or C3 are over zero. If one of them are, it'll calculate, otherwise it'll show an empty string.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Jonno, it worked.  If only I asked you over an hour ago!!!  Lifesaver.